# echo php escaping quotes

Tags: php, escaping

I've tried multiple different variations but there is something wrong with how I am escaping these I believe. The Create Record button doesn't do anything, and the Perm. Delete button doesn't even show up.

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href='deleted.php?author=".$author."&title=".$title."&picfile2=".$picfile2."'>";
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Perm. Delete' onClick='location.href=\"deleted.php?picfile=".$base_path.$picfile."\"'>";
```

Comment: What is the resulted HTML source code ?

Comment: The onClick is being closed with a single-quote whereas it is opened with a PHP escaped double-quote

Comment: <div align='center' id='Charles Bridges--599.jpg'>
    <img src='../pics/deletedrecordpics/Charles Bridges--599.jpg'   class='pictures'>
    <input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record'   onClick="location.href='deleted.php?author=Charles   Bridges&title=&picfile2=599.jpg'>
    input type='button' class='buttons' value='Perm. Delete' onClick='location.href="deleted.php?picfile=Charles+Bridges--599.jpg"'></div>

Comment: There are actually more escaping issues than just one...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Indeed. Which is why I think the [heredoc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21409469/) syntax might be better.

Comment: @AmalMurali I agree but a better suggestion is to avoid inline JS altogether

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Of course. I agree. Inline JS reduces code maintainability and re-usability.

Comment: @AlexanderBridges: Inline JS == Inline JavaScript. So `value='Perm. Delete' onClick='location.href=\"deleted.` is actually inline JS (or inline event handler, to be exact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href=deleted.php?author=$author&title=$title&picfile2=$picfile2\">";
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Perm. Delete' onClick=\"location.href=deleted.php?picfile=$base_path.$picfile\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this:

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href='deleted.php?author=".$author."&title=".$title."&picfile2=".$picfile2."'>";
```

You use **\"** as the opening quote after onClick, but then try to close it with **'**. Once I changed \" to ' things started working.

Answer (score 0):

**You're missing a closing** `\"` **for** `onClick`:

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href='deleted.php?author=".$author."&title=".$title."&picfile2=".$picfile2."'\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first echo you open a doublequote after `onClick=` but never close it:

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href='deleted.php?author=".$author."&title=".$title."&picfile2=".$picfile2."'>";
```

should be

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href='deleted.php?author=".$author."&title=".$title."&picfile2=".$picfile2."'\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Create Record' onClick=\"location.href='deleted.php?author=".$author."&title=".$title."&picfile2=".$picfile2."'**\"**>";
echo "<input type='button' class='buttons' value='Perm. Delete' onClick='location.href=\"deleted.php?picfile=".$base_path.$picfile."\"'>";
```

The second button is not showing up because of the missing \" (see above in bold).

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt close the Escaping, so at the End you have multiple " quotes.
For better structure, sometimes its not always the best solution to put all in one Line. I would have assembled the Link with those variables as a seperate string, and simply put that in.